# Converting of Image File created using image_picker package of flutter to AssetImage/Image.asset?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I am new to flutter, i am building an app where i need to convert the file(image) generated after using image_picker package to asset image to use in the app.

example code as follows, which creates file(Image)

```dart
final Function onSelectImage;

ImageInput(this.onSelectImage);

File _storedImage;


Future<void> _takePicture() async {

        final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                        source: ImageSource.camera,
                        maxWidth: 600,
        );

        if (imageFile == null) {
                return;
        }

        setState(() {
                _storedImage = imageFile;
        });

        final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

        final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');

        widget.onSelectImage(savedImage);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image variable which you can rever to and update when you selected the image.

See the following code:

```dart
final Function onSelectImage;

ImageInput(this.onSelectImage);

File _storedImage;

Image _tempImage;


Future<void> _takePicture() async {

        final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                        source: ImageSource.camera,
                        maxWidth: 600,
        );

        if (imageFile == null) {
                return;
        }

        setState(() {
                _storedImage = imageFile;
        });

        final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

        final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');

        widget.onSelectImage(savedImage);
        setState(() {
          _tempImage = imageFile;
        });


}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _tempImage == null ? Container(child:null) : Image(image: _tempImage);
  }
```

Comment: @Jaron Dob, thanks for the answer, but i am getting following errors  1._tempImage = imageFile - // A value of type 'File' cant be assigned to variable of type 'Image'  2. image:_tempImage // The argument type 'Image'  can't be assigned to the parameter type ImageProvider.

Comment: Hi Sharath, too late to ask, but have you sorted out how to do this ?